# How to trigger ng-change only on drag end from a directive?

Tags: angularjs

It might be a simple fix, but what I want to do is trigger ng-change only on drag-end.

before I did this straight from HTML:

```
    <md-slider aria-label="{{ key }}" step="{{ value.step ? value.step : 1 }}" ng-model="filters.lastAppliedFilter.options[key].current" ng-change="filters.applyValue(filters.lastAppliedFilter.name, key, filters.lastAppliedFilter.options[key].current)" min="{{ value.min ? value.min : 1 }}" max="{{ value.max ? value.max : 250 }}"></md-slider>
```

Values are coming from ng-repeat.

To detect dragend I have created this directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('image.directives').directive('testDragEnd', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('$md.dragend', function() {
                console.info('Drag Ended');
            })
        }
    }
})
```

My question is how I can trigger ng-change only on drag end?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have simply injected service inside of directive:

```
angular.module('image.directives').directive('testDragEnd', ['filters', function(filters) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('$md.dragend', function() {
              var key = attrs.ariaLabel;
              filters.applyValue(filters.lastAppliedFilter.name, key, filters.lastAppliedFilter.options[key].current);
            })
        }
    }
}])
```